# Handling heavy operations that depend on `View`'s dimensions

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, android-lifecycle

I'm implementing a custom `ImageView` that have to load a `Bitmap` from disk. The `Bitmap` should be scaled exactly so, that its width must be equal to the final width a parent layout has been allocated to my `ImageView` and height is calculated to keep an aspect ratio.

So, the question is **what is the proper place during the `View` life cycle to put heavy operations that depend on `View`'s dimensions known after the layout is done?**

(I'd like to keep it simple and not use threads, however.)

1. Most likely it's a bad idea to put that code in `onDraw()` method,
   since it should be as efficient as possible. From the other hand, my
   `ImageView` is unlikely to be resized, so it would kill only the
   first `onDraw()`'s performance and it wouldn't affect any subsequent
   calls to `onDraw()`. So I'm not sure about this option.
2. I could put it at the end of `onLayout(boolean
   changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)` executing my
   heavy code `if (changed == true)`. Is this a good idea?
3. The 3rd option I see is to do it in the `onSizeChanged()` callback.
   My only concern here is whether this callback is **guaranteed** to be
   called only once per actual view's size change. I'm inclined to use
   this option, since in my tests it works fine.

Could someone give an insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the option 2 and 3 works for you to get the View's correct dimensions.

`onDraw()` is called only after `onLayout()`. You can get the dimensions in the `onLayout()` itself and it is better to avoid doing any unnecessary works inside `onDraw()`. So I would choose either option 2 or option 3.

And also be aware that `onSizeChanged()` is sometimes called with zero. Ian [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/pTNy4cRo7wE):

> Be aware too that onSizeChanged() is sometimes called with parameters 
>   of zero -- check for this case, and return immediately (so you don't 
>   get a divide by zero when calculating your layout, etc.).  Some time 
>   later it will be called with the real values.

Another option is to add a runnable to the View's queue, using View.post()

Quote and example [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/4586742):

> The UI event queue will process events in order. After
>   setContentView() is invoked, the event queue will contain a message
>   asking for a relayout, so anything you post to the queue will happen
>   after the layout pass

```
final View view=//smth;
...
view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.getHeight(); //height is ready
            }
        });
```

Using this method, we can be sure that our code is executed only once.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I need to get it executed not once per lifetime of the `View`, but once _per actual size change_, so making a `view.post()` doesn't seem to be right here.

Comment: Oh. Then using the `onSizeChanged()` method would be a better option.

Comment: Ok, from the link you've provided one can infer that `onSizeChanged()` is NOT guaranteed to be called only once per actual `View`'s size change. How to handle it then? Would comparing the old and the new w\h to filter out multiple calls on the same size change be correct in this case?

Comment: Yes. That would be the best way to filter out the duplicate calls on the same size.